# Python: Validating each values in dictionary

Tags: python, validation, dictionary

Whats the best way to validate each values in dictionary with out using any external libraries

```
for example dict = {"A":"some_string",
                    "B":12,
                    "C":83,
                    "D":56.......so on}
```

I have to validate such that if key is `A` then value should be `string` and 
if key is `B` then value should be `int` and ranges from `1 to 20` 
if key is `C` then value should be `int` and ranges from 1 to 100
so based on key,  validation for values also varies...

any shorter way to do it ? my dictionary size is huge

Comment: How many keys are there? And do you have any pattern between corresponding value requirements?

Comment: From where did these rules originate? Without that, it's not a very well defined question.

Comment: create another dictionary with key mapped to validation functions and use something like `validations[key](value)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an approach with another dictionary:

```
d = {"A":"some_string",
     "B":12,
     "C":83,
     "D":56}

# Map your validation functions to the keys
validations = {
    "A": lambda x: isinstance(x, str),
    "B": lambda x: isinstance(x, int) and 1 <= x <= 20,
    "C": lambda x: isinstance(x, int) and 1 <= x <= 100,
}

for k, v in d.items():
    print(validations.get(k, lambda x: False)(v))  # Default validation just returns False (invalid)
```

To check whether the dictionary is valid, you could use:

```
print(all(validations.get(k, lambda x: False)(v) for (k, v) in d.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you define the expected types in a dictionary:

```
typeExpected = {'A':str, 'B':int}
```

meaning that key A should contain a `string` and key B should contain a `int`.   Let's define the dictionary you want to test as:

```
exampleData = {'A':'ok', 'B':0}
```

Now you can verify correctness of the types by running:

```
map(lambda x: type(exampleData[x]) == typeExpected[x], exampleData)
```

Try this on your data and if your dictionary is indeed too big, it would be easy to transform the map into a pool.map to work in multiprocessing.